# How to set a record Dirty ExtJs 6

Tags: extjs, grid, store, extjs6

I want to set a whole record from a store to dirty. I have already tried `record.setDirty()` but this method is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ExtJS Record#Set](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/modern/Ext.data.Model.html#method-set)

The second argument to set accepts an "options" object, where you can specify dirty: true | false

```
record.set({ name: 'value', age: 42}, {
  dirty: true
});

record.set({}, {
  dirty: true
});
```